# How to make a query to get only the data from each user

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a query using 3 tables. The `law`, `article` and `marked`.
I have a website where the user can choose one `law` to read all the `articles`. For each article, the user can marked it or type some description for this article.

The `marker` and `description` is saved on the `marked` table. So, when the user open his law again, all his markations and descriptions will be loaded.

The problem is that in my query, I dont know how show the descriptions and markations of the user logged in. My query is showing the descriptions and markations for all users registered in marked table.

An example of marked table content:

```
 id is_marked  description  article_id  law_id user_id
"0"   "0"       "test1"     "1100"       "3"    "1"
"1"   "0"       "test2"     "1102"       "3"    "1"
```

If I access the `law = 3` with the `user_id =2`, all the description of the `user_id = 1` is showing.

My query:

```
 law = get_object_or_404(Law, pk=pk)    
    articles = Article.objects.filter(law=pk)    
    articles = (
    Article
    .objects
    .filter(law=pk)
    .annotate(
        is_marked=Exists(
            Marked
            .objects
            .filter(
                article_id=OuterRef('id'),
                usuario=request.user,
                is_marked=1,
            )
           )
        )
    .annotate(
        description=(F('markedLaw__description'))        
    ).order_by('id')
```

My model:

```
class Law(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField('Description', blank = True, null=True)


class Article(models.Model):
    article = models.TextField('Article')
    id_article_law = models.IntegerField('Article Law', blank=True, null=True)

    law = models.ForeignKey(Law, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Law', related_name='Articles')


class Marked(models.Model):
    law = models.ForeignKey(Law, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Law', related_name='markedArtigos')
    Article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Article', related_name='markedLaw')
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='markedUsuario', related_name='markedUsuario')
    is_marked = models.BooleanField('Está Marcado?', blank=True, default=False)
    description = models.TextField('Descrição', blank = True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a template tag filter, that will receive the logged in user and article and filter the Marked model.

On this case you would be dealing with it at the template level, no need to do annotations.

Here is the reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Tks for answear, but I really need to solve it in the query.

Comment: Hate to ask it, but why?

Comment: sorry for the delay to answer u. Using template tag filter, Am I not lose performance, because my query will bring a lot of informations?

Comment: not at all. you will bring Article (and only that), then you will query on users description), you are splitting it into two queries, but not bringing more than necessary

Comment: ow great. I'm gonna do that. Tku so much